# Call class directly and not via instance variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created the following two classes in my `classes.js`:

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    display() {
        console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Person
};
```

As you can see I am exporting the two classes via `module.exports`.

```
Person = require('./classes.js');

const someone1 = new Person("First name", "Last name"); // <-- does NOT work

const someone = new Person.Person("First name", "Last name"); // does work
someone.display();
```

However, when calling the classes I get an error, when calling the class directly.

Any suggestions how to call the class directly?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `module.exports = Person;` If you have two classes, well, you want either different files or to do something like `Person = require('../classes.js').Person;`

Comment: Hint: You're exporting an object `{ Person: Person }` from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you're exporting an `object` containing `Person` class

```
module.exports = {
    Person
};
```

So when you import like `Person = require('./classes.js')`

You're actually importing the exported object. So `Person` after you've imported is similar to

```
Person = {
  Person
};
```

You can either change the export by assigning the desired export object to module.exports like:

```
module.exports = Person
```

or change your import to use `destructuring assignment` to import like (notice the curly braces):

```
const { Person } = require('./classes.js');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want all your classes in one file called `classes.js`, then this should work;

```
// classes.js

class Person {
  // ...
}

class Vehicle {
  // ...
}

module.exports = {
  Person,
  Vehicle
}
```

```
// some-other-file.js

const { Person } = require('../classes')

const person = new Person('First', 'Last')
```

Although to keep things easy to understand, my recommendation would be to split your class into multiple files and then export each class from its file directly;

```
class Person {
  // ...
}

module.exports = Person
```

```
const Person = require('../classes/person')

// do something
```

Answer (score 1):

If

```
module.exports = {
    Person
};
```

therefore

```
Person = require('./classes.js').Person;
```

Alternatively, you can

```
module.exports = Person;
```

and

```
Person = require('./classes.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

In `classes.js` you are exporting Person as an object property. So to make it work as you expect you can either do [Destructuring Assignment](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring)

```
const { Person } = require('./classes')
```

Or just require class directly from `classes.js` file.

```
const Person = require('./classes').Person
```

Alternatively, and it's a better option, in my opinion, you can separate Person to its own file and export it by default.

> File `./Person.js`

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    display() {
        console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }
}

module.exports = Person
```

And then in your main file just do:

```
const Person = require('./Person');
```